# JSON_ENCODE encoding contents of included php file

Tags: php, json

Having a weird issue with JSON_ENCODE. I am using php to retrieve data from a database and JSON to pass it to Javascript. It was working perfectly until I included another php file that I intend to use to do some processing on the data before it is returned. After including the file JSON started encoding both the data returned and the contents of the file that I included.

php code:

```
    <?php
    include("GeoLocation.php");//STATEMENT CAUSING JSON TO ACT WEIRDLY
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "go_with_your_mood";

        //$lat=(isset($_GET['lat']))?$_GET['lat']:'';
        //$long=(isset($_GET['long']))?$_GET['long']:'';


    //$geo = new GeoLocation();


$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);   
//Select Database
//mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

//build query
$query = "SELECT * FROM service where service_type = 'security' limit 5";

//Execute query
$qry_result = $mysqli->query($query);

//initial array to encapsulate each individual row
$jsonArray = array();

// Insert a new array for each row returned
while($row = $qry_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rowArray = array($row["id"],$row["name"],$row["address"],$row["suburb"],$row["postcode"],$row["phone"],$row["latitude"],$row["longitude"],$row["description"],$row["service_type"]);
    array_push($jsonArray, $rowArray);
}
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

data that is returned from this file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Data that should be returned:

```
    336,TERANG PUBLIC HOSPITAL,13 AUSTIN AVENUE,TERANG,3264,,-38.23939895629883000000,142.90240478515625000000,,medical,
337,ALFRED PUBLIC HOSPITAL,55 COMMERCIAL ROAD,MELBOURNE,3004,,-37.84560012817383000000,144.98210144042970000000,,medical,
338,CAULFIELD PUBLIC HOSPITAL,260 KOOYONG ROAD,CAULFIELD,3162,,-37.88240051269531000000,145.01669311523438000000,,medical,339,NORTHERN PUBLIC HOSPITAL,185 COOPER STREET,EPPING,3076,,-37.65259933471680000000,145.01510620117188000000,,medical,340,MAFFRA PUBLIC HOSPITAL,42-48 KENT STREET,MAFFRA,3860,,-37.96120071411133000000,146.98339843750000000000,,medical
```

Does anyone know why JSON is returning the contents of the included file as well as my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like short tags `<?` are disabled. And looks like your geolocation.php file starts with `<?` instead of `<?php`
Either edit your geolocation.php file and replace `<?` with `<?php` in the start.

Or include it like following

```
include( 'GeoLocation.php' );
```

Meaning include it by putting space before and after or copy paste the include code at it is written above. Hopefully one of these solutions work.

Alternatively, if you can then enable short tags.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the quick fix. :)